# Getting repeated rows with unexpected values in HIVE joins query

Tags: mysql, sql-server, hadoop, hive

when i run the following query in hive i am getting repeated rows with wrong values which are not presented in both the tables,

```
SELECT year_1992.id, year_1992.total, year_1993.total

FROM year_1992 INNER JOIN year_1993 ON (year_1992.id = year_1993.id)

order by year_1992.id;
```

Here i have two tables, both contains id and total columns where id values are same, i want to display id, total of `table_1992` and total of `table_1993`.

following is the result of above query,

```
451211  8327    9108

452111  87384   88720

452111  85153   88720(here 85153-wrong value)

452111  87384   86325(here 86325-wrong value)

452111  85153   86325(here 85153, 86325-wrong valuee)

452112  93871   103405

452112  91936   103405

452112  93871   101360

452112  91936   101360
```

i even tried with distinct, but still same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have duplicate values in the Id field. That is why the rows are getting repeated. You'll need to add an aggregate function and a group by clause or change the way you join the two tables
This will remove all the duplicates, but will sum up all the totals. OR you could show the MAX, MIN, AVG, etc....

```
SELECT year_1992.id, 
SUM(year_1992.total) AS 'year_1992.sum', 
SUM(year_1993.total) AS 'year_1993.sum',

MAX(year_1992.total) AS 'year_1992.MAX', 
MAX(year_1993.total) AS 'year_1993.MAX'

MAX(year_1992.total) AS 'year_1992.MIN', 
MAX(year_1993.total) AS 'year_1993.MIN',

MAX(year_1992.total) AS 'year_1992.AVG', 
MAX(year_1993.total) AS 'year_1993.AVG'

FROM year_1992 
    INNER JOIN year_1993 ON (year_1992.id = year_1993.id)
GROUP BY year_1992.id
ORDER BY year_1992.id;
```

Also, because of the inner join, there's a chance that not all rows will be returned, but only rows where there's a matching id in both tables.

Hope that helps